# c# how do i compare two string that have matching letters but one has a whitespace

Tags: c#, string, if-statement, whitespace, equals

Here is my code below, how can I make the `if` return true as it currently skips over the `if` statement because of the string values has a space in it.

```
string instrucType = "FM";
string tenInstrucType = "FM ";
if (tenInstrucType.Equals(instrucType))
{
    blLandlordContactNumberHeader.Visible = true;
    lblLandlordContactNumber.Text = landlordData.LandlordContact.DefPhone;
    lblLandlordEmailHeader.Visible = true;
    lblLandlordEmail.Text = landlordData.LandlordContact.DefEmail;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the Trim function:

```
if (tenInstrucType.Trim().Equals(instrucType.Trim()))
```

This will only trim from the ends though.  If there is a possibility of a space in the middle, use the Replace.

Answer (score 1):

If whitespace is only located on the end of string, trim both strings:

```
if (tenInstrucType.Trim().Equals(instrucType.Trim()))
```

If you want to ignore all white space characters, you could remove them from string:

```
string normalized1 = Regex.Replace(tenInstrucType, @"\s", "");
string normalized2 = Regex.Replace(instrucType, @"\s", "");

if (normalized1 == normalized2) // note: you may use == and Equals(), as you like
{         
    // ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this condition:

```
if (tenInstrucType.Replace(" ",string.Empty).Equals(instrucType.Replace(" ",string.Empty))
```

Answer (score 0):

Trim the strings:

```
if (tenInstrucType.Trim().Equals(instrucType.Trim()))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (tenInstrucType.Replace(" ","").Equals(instrucType.Replace(" ","")))
```

using `Trim` may seem proper for this case, but note that `Trim` only removes leading or ending spaces; inner spaces are not removed.